# want to remove the space between two divisions using css

Tags: css, html

which CSS property can use to decrease the space between two division in the UI.
i applied padding but -ve values are not working in padding. some one can help me?

Comment: .center-align{
padding-bottom: 15px;
}

Comment: I don't think the javascript, html5 or angularjs tags need to be here.. CSS will suffice.

Comment: There's no space between `div`s natively, you've to check your stylesheets for margins and paddings to remove the space.

Comment: Specify whether it is about vertical or horizontal space. Provide with the HTML markup. Provide with the current CSS applied (if any). Without this information we can only speculate and guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the start do

```
li { margin-bottom: 0; margin-top: 0;}
```

since by default `li` element has bottom/top (depending on a browser) margin.
If you need to "squeeze" the elements even more, then go with the negative values for the margin.

Comment: Thnaks @spliter. i fixed that issue

Answer (score 0):

Try margin instead of padding. Margin can have -ve value

Answer (score 0):

**Use this in css with your  class or ID**

clear:both;

or

clear:right;

or

clear:left;